# for test automating a form , i need to fill out a month and year in form,but the month is only getting filled ,year is not

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

this html element

```html
<input type="month" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" placeholder="From" id="id_From_Duration1" name="From_Duration1" value="" maxlength="7" onfocus="(this.type='month')" min="1940-01" max="2025-12">
<small class="text-muted"> Format:YYYY-MM</small>
```

i tried to do this way

```
self.webdriver.find_element_by_name("From_Duration1").click()
self.webdriver.find_element_by_name(i).send_keys("032019", Keys.ENTER)
```

there is no day needed ,the form should be filled like this eg. March 2019

Comment: Cand you provide DOM?

Comment: Are you getting an error?